# Bootstrap v5.0 Toggle Button not revealing nav-item

Tags: navbar, togglebutton, bootstrap-5, hamburger-menu

Linked HTML file with bootstrap-v5, copied exact code from documentation.
Toggle button on the right not revealing "nav-item".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">    <!--class of bootsrap -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" style="padding-left: 10px;">Code Decipher</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">

                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Content</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you link bootstrap JS file ?

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: No, i didn't do that.. Now it's working thank you.

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava: Please be sure to mark this answer as accepted by clicking the checkbox next to it. That will communicate to others that this is resolved. It will also reward both you and the author with some reputation.